# File does not exist using PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file)

Tags: php

I am trying to import excel file using library PHPexcel, but when choosing file and submitting it, it fires Error : Unable to load the file : "1.xlsx": Could not open 1.xlsx for reading! File does not exist... why? can you help plz!

here is code:

```
<form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(0);
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{ 
    $name = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $ex = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename = $name. '.' .$ex;

    try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error : Unable to load the file : "'.pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'],PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

if i want to write the file path instead of `$filename` and the file in the project itself, what can i write?

Comment: The `filename` argument to `load()` can be a filepath, not simply a name.... the rules for the `filename` argument are the same as those for PHP's own filesystem functions like `fopen()` or `file_get_content()`

Comment: If you look at the examples, you'll find that many of them do use a filepath, not simply a filename; likewise in the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/03-Loading-a-Spreadsheet.md)

Comment: but i am selecting the file and submetting, it may be any where.. ho can i get its path in this situation ?

Comment: Your script isn't running in the same directory as the temporary file uploads..... how to get the path? `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Comment: @MarkBaker is that what should i put instead of `$filename`?

Comment: As you're doing this immediately after the upload, and before any move_uploaded_file() call, then yes.... you need to use the $_FILES details of where the uploaded file has been placed in the filesystem

Comment: @MarkBaker i tried `$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ttt/';
        $filename = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);`  ... but nothing changes..

Comment: `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`, not `$_FILES['file']['name']`.... but __don't__ use `basename()`.... you want the full filepath, not simply the name of the file (which is what basename() gives you).... and stop trying to tie it to document root.... `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` gives you the exact filepath

Comment: @MarkBaker it's working ... thank you so much..
you can put it as answer and i'll vote it :)))